# Merging gh-pages into github-pages tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I propose to merge [gh-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gh-pages) tag (6 followers, 120 questions) into [github-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-pages) tag (59 followers, 615 questions).

Those two tags are pointing to the exact same subject : hosting static pages on github architecture.

Comment: Fully agree. This is probably something we can do manually if we get consensus.

Answer (score 4):

They are completely synonymous. If you were to unshortify? the tags, it would literally be the same thing.

```
gh = github

gh-pages = github-pages = github-pages
```

That logic.